# Jquery rotate: stop endless rotation

Tags: jquery

I'm using this plugin http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

```
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
  angle+=3;
 $("#img").rotate(angle);
},50)
```

I would like to stop the rotation when I click on #img but that doesn't work.

```
$("#img").stopRotate();
```

Is there a way to stop the setInterval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you store your [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval#Example) call in a variable, you can then call [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) on it which will stop it.

```
var angle = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    angle+=3;
    $("#img").rotate(angle);
},50)

$("#img").click(function() {
    clearInterval(interval); // stick the clearInterval in a click event
});
```